# How to decrypt single EncFS encrypted files?

Tags: files, encryption, data-recovery, encfs

Is it possible to decrypt single EncFS encrypted files with access to .encfs6.xml configuration file and without the proper directory structure it was created?

With a little help from google I found this comment on a blog post:

> http://pragmattica.wordpress.com/2009/05/10/encrypting-your-dropbox-seamlessly-and-automatically/
>
> Comment by Spence — August 14, 2009 @ 11:44 pm | Reply
>
> I did some reading on this, and without the metadata information
>   included in the .encfs6.xml file, it is impossible to decrypt ANY of
>   the files. If you wanted to decrypt a single file, you would at least
>   need to have a directory with that file, and then the encrypted file
>   that you wanted, with all of the proper directory structure. I haven’t
>   played with this much myself, but I think it might be possible to
>   mount something set up like that, and then you could get at the file.
>   However, since the filename is encrypted, you wouldn’t know which file
>   to download from Dropbox
>
> There is a debug utility that you can use on the command-line to get
>   the decrypted filenames of files, and possibly decrypt them as well,
>   so the situation isn’t hopeless. It would probably just take a lot of
>   playing around to figure this stuff out. If you do invest the time and
>   figure some of this out, maybe write a post about it on your blog and
>   link to it here.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hmmmm. I thought it would be possible as long as `externalIVChaining` is off, but experimentally, this doesn't seem to be the case. Encfs's documentation is sadly sparse. I suggest asking on the mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`jefsr`](http://code.google.com/p/jefsr/), a Java EncFS Reader library.